# Jquery loop through a Json object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Json Code

```
{
 "pizza":
 {
   "pepperoni lovers":
   {
      "topping": "pepperoni",
      "crust": "hand tossed"
   },

   "sausage lovers":
   {
      "topping": "sausage",
      "crust": "hand tossed"
   }
 }
```

}

How could I loop through this and populate an array with just the names?

Comment: Is that a typo, or are you really missing the required `:` on each pizza type

Comment: This is not valid JSON.

Comment: Not using jQuery for the loops could save you some headaches…

Comment: @FelixKling 
Thanks for the link.  I'm coming from the XML world.  I had no idea I could restructure my code to have an array inside the .json file.  That made it a lot easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery, assuming a correct object

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/abHvk/)

```
var pizzaNames=[],
    data = { "pizza" : {
      "pepperoni lovers":
    {
       "topping": "pepperoni",
       "crust": "hand tossed"
    },
      "sausage lovers":
      {
       "topping": "sausage",
       "crust": "hand tossed"
      }
   }
}
// $.each is IE8 compatible, Object.keys is not
$.each(data.pizza,function(name,val) {
   pizzaNames.push(name);
});
```

Comment: How would you get the values of only pepperoni lovers (topping, crust) if you didn't want to hard code the name "pepperoni lovers"?

Comment: I do not understand the question. Can you give me the full use case here?

Comment: Never mind.  I'm coming from the XML world.  I didn't know that you can have an array in Json.  Once I found that out everything else fell into place.  Thanks for answering quickly though.

Answer (score 3):

An array of property names? Use [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys):

```
var names = Object.keys(data.pizza);
```

Comment: Does this account for the property names of the inner objects?

Comment: @Rick: No, but I don't think the OP wants them - I assume that he is only interested in the pizza names.

Comment: Clever. I always think $.each in these cases...

Answer (score 1):

The classic way to iterate over an object is to use a `for .. in` loop.

```
for (prop in obj) {
    val = obj[prop];
}
```

One possible side-effect of this technique is that you are not guaranteed to iterate over the properties in any particular order. If you know the property names ahead of time, you could create an array of property names and iterate.

Since your objects are nested, you will need to nest two `for .. in` loops to iterate thoroughly:

```
for (prop in obj) {
    nested_obj = obj[prop];

    for (nested_prop in nested_obj) {
        nested_val = nested_obj[nested_prop];
    }
}
```

To get an array of all of the property names, you can build the array like this:

```
props = [];

for (prop in obj) {
    props.push(prop);
    nested_obj = obj[prop];

    for (nested_prop in nested_obj) {
        props.push(nested_prop);
        nested_val = nested_obj[nested_prop];
    }
}
```

Comment: He says the object was from JSON (or maybe an object literal), so there won't be anything enumerable on the prototype chain anyways.

Comment: Great point, Bergi. Old habits die hard.

Comment: Also he only needed prop in top object and not obj[prop]

Comment: That last part was not explicitly made clear.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through an objects properties with for...in:

```
a = [];
for (n in pizza) {
    a.push(n);
}
```

Comment: This is [not "loop like an array"](http://stackoverflow.com/q/500504/1048572) (though the code is correct here).